# Keep currency symbol and amount on same line in VF

Tags: visualforce, html, quote, currency

I have create a VF page for (PDF) quote generation however i'm struggling keeping the currency symbol and amount together.

[image]

Looking at my code ...

```
{!$Label.Quote_PDF_AgreesOnPlanned_Act}
    <b>
    {!
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "USD","$ ", 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "EUR","€ ", 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "JPY","¥ ", 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "GBP","£ ", 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'DKK','DK', 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'CHF','Sf',              
         Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode)
    )))))
    }
    </b>
    <b> 
    <!-- Hide when subscription = true -->
    <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}" rendered="{!!showSubscriptionsTable}">
       <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Amount}" ></apex:param>
    </apex:outputText>
    </b>
```

Comment: Try solving it with the HTML tag &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

You need to slightly modify your code to add a non breaking space code like below to all of your equivalent lines:

```
IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "USD","$&nbsp;",
```

Doing that should cause the currency symbol to stay with the value and not allow the break to occur.

Comment: other enhancements would include using a CASE formula and moving the currency symbol logic into a reusable VF custom component

Comment: That did not help I'm afraid ... now the line says ..Hereby Mr Stein agrees on the scope and planned activities for the amount of €&nsp;
169,100.00 (based on actual costs excl. VAT).

Comment: I made a typo. That should be `&nbsp;`. My apologies. Will fix it in my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Change this code:

```
    </b>
    <b>
```

To this code:

```
    </b>&nbsp;<b>
```

You need to make sure that there's no white space, or HTML will be allowed to break there. In fact, you could really just take out that bit of code:

```
{!$Label.Quote_PDF_AgreesOnPlanned_Act}
    <b>
    {!
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "USD","$ ", 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "EUR","€ ", 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "JPY","¥ ", 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = "GBP","£ ", 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'DKK','DK', 
      IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'CHF','Sf',

         Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode)
    )))))
    }<!-- Hide when subscription = true 
    --><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}" rendered="{!!showSubscriptionsTable}">
       <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Amount}" ></apex:param>
    </apex:outputText>
    </b>
```

It's all about white-space management.

Comment: It also depends somewhat on the customer's requirements for how "pretty" they want it to look. Not everyone will find the lack of the non-breaking space appealing, but I agree he could remove all of the `If` statements. +1

Comment: Stipped the code back to this .. and no luck ... i'm not even sure if this would be duable using Case control. It's a pitty sfdc lack support of string method with parameters from VF. Then I could solve it with an simple method .. (function).

Comment: {!$Label.Quote_PDF_AgreesOnPlanned_Act}
        <b>
        {!
          IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'US','$', 
          IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR','€', 
          IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'CHF','Sf',Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode)
        ))
        }
        <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}" rendered="{!!showSubscriptionsTable}">
           <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Amount}"></apex:param>
        </apex:outputText>

Answer (score -1):

Seems devil was in the details. "white-space management" triggered me to look closer .... removing the blanks here `value="{0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}"` worked magic ...

Comment: What blanks are you referring to? This looks the same as the code you posted.